# Making recursive function in python

Tags: python, recursion

This is a homework problem. I try to get a recursive function:

```
def problem_a(n):
    answer.append(n)
    if n == 1:
        return answer    
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        answer.append(n/2)
    else :
        answer.append(n*3 + 1)
        problem_a(n*3 + 1)
```

This code obviously doesn't work as `answer` isn't defined as a list. With loops it would work, but I want to make a recursive function. I could just use as input a list, but I wonder if there exist something more elegant.

`problem_a(7)` should give as output:

```
[7, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40 , 20, 10 ,5 ,16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative solution to the ones that have been suggested so far (which use an extra argument to pass the list up the recursive chain) is to build the final list as you return from the recursion. This is not terribly efficient, since concatenating lists requires copying both of them, but it will work:

```
def problem_a(n):
    if n == 1:
        return [n]
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return [n] + problem_a(n // 2)
    else:
        return [n] + problem_a(3*n + 1)
```

Comment: @Kasper `//` is for py3.x, it truncates the decimal digits.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a local variable `answer` and pass it around in recursive calls.

```
def problem_a(n, answer = None):
    answer = [n] if answer is None else answer
    if n == 1:
        return answer
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        n = n/2
        answer.append(n)
    else:
        n = n*3 + 1
        answer.append(n)
    return problem_a(n, answer)

print problem_a(7)
```

**output:**

```
[7, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try a generator:

```
def problem_a(n):
    yield n
    if n == 1:
        return
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        x = n / 2
    else:
        x = n * 3 + 1

    for y in problem_a(x):
        yield y

print list(problem_a(7))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your skeleton solution. You need to recurse when `n % 2 == 0` as well as in the final `else`. The `answer` variable is given a default value so that it is initialized to `[]` when the function is first called without an argument.

```
def problem_a(n, answer=None):
    if answer == None:
        answer = []

    answer.append(n)
    if n == 1:
        return answer    
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return problem_a(n/2, answer)
    else :
        return problem_a(n*3 + 1, answer)

>>> problem_a(7)
[7, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

**Edit**

As per the comments, using a mutable default argument is a bad idea. Just set it to None like in the other posts and check if its None to create a new list. I changed the answer to reflect this.

The original bad code was as follows:

```
def problem_a(n, answer=[]):
    answer.append(n)
    ...
```

Comment: I recommend using answer=None and check for None. You should never use mutables as default arguments, as they can be mutated easily and only a reference will be handed around. That's dangerous!

Comment: Using a [mutable default argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) is a bad idea. It will only work as intended if you only ever call it only once.

Comment: Thanks to the comments! I didn't know that that trick was a bad idea :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a closure:

```
>>> def s():
    ret = []
    def f(n):
        ret.append(n)
        if n % 2 == 0:
            f(int(n/2))
        elif n != 1:
            f(int(n*3 + 1))
        return ret
    return f

>>> s()
<function f at 0x00000000033A5848>
>>> s()(7)
[7, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```